# Unable to import .ddl file into postgress server

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgress and psql. I have `.ddl` file which contains postgres database dump(With 10K lines of SQL statements).

For start, I am able to create database from psql shell with command - `create database test;`

Now, I am trying to import the `.ddl` file into `test` database but I cannot figure it out. Below is the syntax I am using in shell -

[image]

Please can anyone help me in importing the file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to start `psql` from within `psql`  - just use `\i` if you are already inside `psql`

Comment: Ohk..I did `\i c:/users/desktop/file.ddl test` it loaded tables into default `postgres DB` and not `test` DB. How Do I import it to `test` Db?

Comment: You need to connect to that database, e.g.  `\connect test` This is all described in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)